# function that takes an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> and returns a ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> throws errors

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I have a function `insertQuestions()`, which inserts a few Entries into a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and later returns the changed `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Here is the code

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> insertQuestions(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> textmatrix)
    {
        return textmatrix;
    }
```

now i do realise that this function doesnt do anything yet, but the problem is, it fails to compile, because it "Expects an expression" in the arguments-field of the function. Any help regarding this error would be appreciated. I might be reaching to high, but this could be a AndroidStudio/Compiler-Error as well, because if i do it in 2 steps `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> -> String -> ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` it works...

**EDIT:** turns out im stupid for not noticing AndroidStudio creating the function insde another function... thanks @AdnanElezovic

Cheers

Jacobus

Comment: Looks like an OK function declaration. Check the code above your function, it's probably in the wrong scope (maybe inside another function instead of being below it)

Comment: Also check if the imports are correct.

Comment: @AdnanElezovic I've just checked that, and it turns out it created the function in the Thread instead of below the function... thanks. the weird part is tho, that it never threw errors, when had i had go from list<list> to string or vice versa. Thanks alot tho <3

Comment: @Egor thanks for the suggestion. imports were all correct. turns AndroidStudio created the Function inside another Function without me noticing... and i already started going insane